# Why Cronjob (Qunatz scheduler) is generating duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, struts2, jpa-2.0, quartz-scheduler

In my application for generating a unique no I am using a Quartz scheduler Cronjob (I had to use Cronjob because no manual intervention is there to generating that no).

But some how it had generated unique no for some time after that I found that No. duplicating then when I check the log file of my jboss server

I found this

2014-04-16 00:29:00,164 INFO  [IportLogger] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9) =======update Doc Series of FIRSTWGT weight ===The next no we get here is =================76

2014-04-16 08:52:00,189 INFO  [IportLogger] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7) =======updateDocSeries of FIRSTWGT weight ===The next no we get here is =================76

how this happened ?

Same no has generated 2 times at 2 different times ?
I'm using struts 2 and jpa 2 and sql server as my database.

Anyone can give me a hint about this???

There may be N no of transaction tables are in the project , each transaction will be identified by it's "doc series code", and for that particular table if user post a transaction successfully I will allocate transaction No from doc series table where it will maintain a variable called "next No" for that particular series and it will be incremented manually each time when a transaction is posted by user,

here in my case i am allocating the unique no by cronjob, by increment the "Next No" each time please observe the following code

```
FirstWeight firstWeight=new  FirstWeight();

IptDocumentseries ids   =  dochelper.getDocSeriesNo("FIRSTWGT"); //  FIRSTWGT is doc series for a table called first weight

Long nextno   = ids.getNextNo();

//System.out.println("value of doc no." +nextno);

firstWeight.setDocNum(nextno);
                            firstWeight.setDocStatus("Approved");

FWDao.update(firstWeight);//saving into database

dochelper.updateDocSeries("FIRSTWGT",firstWeight.getDocSeriesCode());



public synchronized void updateDocSeries(String doccode,String docseries) 
    {

        Long nextno= 0L;

        List<IptDocumentseries>   idslist =iidsd.findByDocSeriesCode(doccode,docseries); 

        try{  

            System.out.println("The List size of the idslist is : "+idslist.size());

            if(idslist!=null && !idslist.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("The List size of the idslist is inside if : "+idslist.size());
                nextno   = idslist.get(0).getNextNo();

                IptDocumentseries ids = new IptDocumentseries();
                ids = idslist.get(0);
                ids.setNextNo(++nextno);
                IportLogger.log("=======updateDocSeries===The next no we get here is ================="+ nextno);
                    if(doccode.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTWGT"))
                {
            Logger.log("=======updateDocSeries of FIRSTWGT weight ===The next no we get here is ================="+ nextno);
                }
                ids.setModifiedDate(getCurrentTimeStamp());
                System.out.println("The next no we get here is "+ nextno);
                iidsd.update(ids);
            }
        }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: Please check the code, Aleksandr M.